# Prettify JSON data using Ruby on the terminal

Tags: ruby, json

I have earlier used Python for doing pretty output of JSON data like this:

```
python -mjson.tool input.json
```

I wanted to get similar output using Ruby. I am doing it like this:

```
ruby -rrubygems -e 'require "json"; ARGV.each { |f| print JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.load(File.open(f))) }'  input.json
```

This is a lot for a small shell command. Can you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten your script:

```
# ruby 1.9.2
ruby -rjson -e 'ARGF.each(nil) {|f| puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(f)) }'  file1 file2 

# ruby 1.8.7
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "json"; ARGF.each(nil) {|f| puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(f)) }'  file1 file2
```

> [ARGF](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html) is a stream designed for use in scripts that process files given
>   as command-line arguments or passed in via STDIN.

I pass `nil` to `ARGF#each` method to split `ARGF` by files, not by lines (default behavior of `#each`).

Comment: ruby: no such file to load -- json (LoadError)

Comment: @tuxdna, looks like you use ruby 1.8.7, it does not handle `-r` correctly, I updated my example

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem [colorful_json](https://github.com/simon/colorful_json) which does exactly that.

Comment: I just installed colorful_json. It gives error:$ cjson mapping.json 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/library.rb:75:in `ffi_lib': Could not open library 'lib.so': lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/library.rb:54:in `map'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/library.rb:54:in `ffi_lib'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.5.3/lib/rubypython/python.rb:29
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubypython-0.5.3/lib/rubypython.rb:261:in `load'
...

Comment: Looks like this is the issue: [link](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb/issues/10)

Comment: Yes. I installed python-devel package and it worked. So, behind the scenes, colorful_json uses Python  ;-)

Comment: @tuxdna yes, it uses Pygments to highlight syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the awesome_print gem.

1. Install it with: gem install awesome_print
2. Create a Bash function which will act as a shortcut

   ```
   function jcurl { curl -s $* | ruby -rawesome_print -rjson -e 'ap JSON.parse(STDIN.read)'; }; export -f jcurl
   ```
3. Use your function to get pretty JSON in your Linux terminal:

   ```
   jcurl http://127.0.0.1:3000/persons/1.json
   ```